# How to build cpp project for Windows CE car stereo?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, embedded, windows-ce

I have a cpp project, that i try to build in vs2008, for Windows CE on my car stereo.
I only have the options in vs2008 to build for Windows Mobile 6 pro or windows mobile pocket pc 5. But none of these options builds a working exe file.
When downloading a precompiled file, it works fine.

So my questinon is how do i build this project?
Which packages do i have to install, in order to have the right build options?

Comment: hi, You probably need SDK from your radio to build a working exe.

Comment: See my answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507567/vs2005-and-windows-ce-6-0-debugging

Answer (score 2):

As already suggested by Luka the best option is to have an SDK for that specific device.
If the device manufacturer does not provide it you should at least check the CPU type and Windows CE version to try to get a compatible SDK. In this case you may reference some functions that are not actually available on the device or not being able to reference some that are actually available, but this should not prevent you from doing a build.